# java application fails to login in linux environment

Tags: java, linux, hibernate, jdbc

I have written a cron which is supposed to make database connection and do some updation and deletion operations . The cron runs fine in windows using batch file but it fails saying :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling
Driver#connect
        at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
        at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
        at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
        at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
        at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
        at
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
        at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
        at
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
        at in.AuditCronProcessor.main(AuditCronProcessor.java:36)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user01'@'10.65.28.69'
(using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
```

In the code ,i am using StandardServiceRegistry to close the operations once the activity is done :

```
 String url="jdbc:mysql://"+arg[0]+":"+arg[1]+"/updatedb";
 AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();

 config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
 config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", arg[2]);
 config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", arg[3].trim());

 StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();

 SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(registry);
```

i am using .sh file to run the above cron . It runs fine using commandline, but encounters the error while running using .sh file.
Any clues :(

Regards
Jayendra

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this command on MySQL command interpreter.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON updatedb.* TO 'user01'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Which will grant the `user01` to connect from any host.

Comment: it is running fine in windows environment with the same user ie "user01"  but fails while running it from .sh file in linux . and user01 have privilleges : grant all privileges on *.* to root2 @ localhost identified by password xxxx.

Comment: If your user01 and database is created from Windows environment then its IP is enabled to login. But when the IP changes it throws the Access denied for user 'user01'@'10.65.28.69'. You need to Grant permission to access from any IP.